# How to re-enable iptables on Fedora 18?

Tags: fedora, iptables, firewalld

[FirewallD](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/FirewallD) is the default firewall in Fedora 18. I have been using `iptables`  for quite some time and have a custom configuration which I need for logging of ip traffic. I am not used to the new graphical interface which seems to lack many of the functionalities present in the old one, that can be loaded with ease.

I tried to re-enable the old iptables with the following commands:

```
# systemctl stop firewalld.service
# systemctl start iptables.service
# systemctl start ip6tables.service
```

The messages log shows:

> systemd 1 Started IPv4 firewall with iptables. 
>   systemd 1 Started IPv6 firewall with ip6tables.

But from `systemctl -t service -a`, I can see that both remain inactive and dead, despite being loaded.

Nevertheless, I tried loading the custom configuration with

```
iptables-restore < iptables.conf
```

but got a series of warnings:

> WARNING: The state match is obsolete. Use conntrack instead.
>   WARNING: The state match is obsolete. Use conntrack instead.
>   WARNING: The state match is obsolete. Use conntrack instead.
>   WARNING: The state match is obsolete. Use conntrack instead.
>   WARNING: The state match is obsolete. Use conntrack instead.

What should I do to get iptables back to work?

Comment: The _kernel_ format for firewally things is still iptables, there are convenience wrappers (and GUIs, and ...), those have changed quite a bit (and probably are different among distributions too).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks to me like that is because of a new version of iptables that came out in October. `-m state --state` has been obsoleted in favour of `-m conntrack --ctstate`.  Hence, *"The state match is obsolete. Use conntrack instead."*

http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-940302-start-0.html

http://blog.yjl.im/2012/11/iptables-state-match-is-obsolete-use.html

'conntrack' is in my man page (1.4.14, which is *not* the newest one):

> conntrack
>          This module, when combined with connection tracking, allows access to the connection tracking state for this packet/connection.
>
> [!] --ctstate statelist
>                 statelist is a comma separated list of the connection states to match.  Possible states are listed below.
>
> [...]
>
> States for --ctstate:
>
> INVALID
>        meaning that the packet is associated with no known connection
>
> NEW    meaning that the packet has started a new connection, or otherwise associated with a connection which has not seen packets in
>   both directions, and
>
> ESTABLISHED
>                 meaning that the packet is associated with a connection which has seen packets in both directions,
>
> RELATED
>                 meaning that the packet is starting a new connection, but is associated with an existing connection, such as an FTP data
>   transfer, or an ICMP error.
>
> [...]

Thanks for the heads up on this, BTW.

Comment: Thumbs up, that solve the problem. By the way, how do I save it? `/usr/libexec/iptables.init save` does not work anymore.

Comment: I just edit iptables.conf directly.  If you know how to use the directives, that's all it is.  You can also write the current state out with `iptables-save > somefile`, and if that looks good, copy iptables.conf to a separate backup if you want, and replace it with somefile.

Comment: Ah, yes, of course. I forgot about that. Thanks :)